# Conductor in motion in a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, induction

I have the following exercise: there is a square conductor of a given side L and resistance R. The conductor is surrounded by a magnetic field B (90° with the y-axis) and it depends from z: B(z) = K*z, where K is a given constant.
Now I have to determinare the current that circulates in the conductor when it's dropped.
[image: 1]]

That's what I tried to do:
first of all the induced current is given by $ i = \frac{\epsilon}{R}$
 where $\epsilon$ is given by:
$$\epsilon = - \frac{d}{dt}(\phi(\vec B))$$
I calculated the flow using:
$$\int_S{\vec B* \hat n *d \vec S} = KzL^2$$
so the current should be (assuming that $z(t) = \frac{1}{2}gt^2$:
$$\epsilon = KL^2\frac{d}{dt}(z) = KL^2gt = > i(t) = \frac{KL^2g}{R}t $$

Please can you tell me if this is correct and, in case, what and why did I do wrong? Thank you so much in advance!